# Arduino MKRFox1200 Configuration

Tags: arduino

I want to install a `Arduino MKRFox1200` . 
I've installed the drivers,

[image]

but i can't find it in the IDE

[image]

and even its installed I see this message in the IDE

[image]

and this is the result of **Get Board Info**, but the board is flashing green

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the MKRFox board support package.

Follow the [getting started instructions](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/MKRFox1200) and add the Atmel SAMD Core to your Arduino IDE from the Board Manager.

After you installed it, you should be able to select select the MKRFOX1200 in Tools>Board